# error 1064(42000) while import via .sql file inside windows 7

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-error-1064

error 1064(42000) while import via .sql file inside windows 7.

This exactly same command when use in linux server, no error.

But when use in windows 7, it show error 1064.

If I manually paste the create, grant, flush line by line into command line and press enter, then it can go through.

not sure why it cannot go through when is stored inside .sql file.

```
mysql -u root -p123 < C:/inetpub/createschema.sql;
```

createschema.sql

```
create database db_aa;
grant ALL on db_aa.* to 'root'@'localhost';
flush privileges;

create database db_bb;
grant ALL on db_bb.* to 'root'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```